# Superscript ® in Title bar

Tags: xcode, ipad, superscript

I need to insert the `®` character as a superscript into the title bar of an app for the iPad. How can this be done in XCode?

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 5.x, you can't set text attributes like bold, superscript, etc. on individual characters within a label's text. (This includes the builtin labels of navigation bars.)

You can just insert the ® character in your string (you can type it on a US Mac keyboard with option-R, or use the escape code as in Jessedc's answer). Whether it appears small and superscript depends on the font used for the label -- some fonts make that symbol appear as such already, others make it larger and baseline-aligned.

Comment: Love the slight hint given by "as of iOS 5.x" ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Grab the unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ae/index.htm)

put it in a string

```
NSString *string = @"\u00AE"; //this is your (r)
```

Nearly a duplicate of [How do I escape a Unicode character in my Objective-C source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833822/how-do-i-escape-a-unicode-character-in-my-objective-c-source-code)