# stringWithFormat converts German umlauts

Tags: nsmutablearray, converters, stringwithformat

I have an **NSMutableArray miniResults** which contains the following NSStrings.

**List 1, Some strings have German umlauts.**
[image]

After putting **miniResults** into NSString solution with this:

```
solution    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",miniResults];
```

solution contains converted strings what I don´t want.

**List 2, All umlauts converted!**
[image]

I don´t see why this happens.
What am I doing wrong?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler seems to escape them to unicode. Shouldn't be a problem anyfurther. I've got no sources for this, but it looks like that.

One possible fast solution would be substituting them. Make "Ae" from "Ä", etc.

Comment: Yes, but I don´t want to to do this. I would like to understand why this happens.

Comment: This happens because they are non-ascii characters. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)

Comment: It might also have historical reasons as the 3rd comment on the first answer on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833822/how-do-i-escape-a-unicode-character-in-my-objective-c-source-code) mentions.

Comment: I don´t see this. At the moment I´m filling these strings into an NSString instead into an NSMutableArray: gesamtString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",gesamtString, theLineString]; And this does´t change the umlauts.

Comment: Well, seems I'm out here. This is a job for those apple nerds out there. Objective-C is a weird language to me at all. Sorry for being not helpfull.