# Using octal character gives warning: multi-character character constant

Tags: c

Following the logic from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755741/character-constant-000-xhh), the following code *should* work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("%c", '\0101');
    return 0;
}
```

However, [it gives the following error](https://repl.it/@SigmaG/CTroubles):

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:5:18: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     printf("%c", '\0101');
                  ^~~~~~~
exit status -1
```

I am not sure why it is a multi-character constant. I believe there should only be a single character constant inside those single quotes (octal `101` = decimal `65` = `'A'`). Why are there more than one characters? And why isn't octal notation not working?

Comment: I'm no C expert, but octal character literals are 3-digits, aren't they? You don't specify the initial 0, that's just for numeric literals I think.

Comment: `'\0101'` -> `'\101'`

Comment: Why the error is talking about `"%s"` while the code has `"%c"`?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen For character literals leading zero is not needed. It is needed for integer octal literals. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape ... update ah.. it's for C++.. but same idea

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry, I copied the wrong code, that `%s` is a typo. Although if you run the `repl` file I linked to, it gives the same error I was talking about. Also, it seems that the cppreference link is the answer I needed. Could you please post an answer? Thanks!

Comment: when writing an OCTAL character, use a leading 0 but do NOT use a leading '\'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be `'\101'` not `'\0101'`. You can use `'\x41'`*(Hexadecimal)* or `'\101'`*(octal)* instead of `'A'`. But both reduces the *portability* and *readability* of your code. You should only consider using *escape sequences* when there isn't a better way to represent the character.

Comment: Or you can use `'A'` for `'A'` :D

Comment: @EugeneSh. that was just for demonstration purpose xD

Comment: Can you explain how it reduces _portability_ even if it is in standard?

Comment: @snr `'A'` gives you an `A` no matter what your machine's character set is. `'\101'` and the like assume ASCII.

Comment: Unless you explicitly want to have `\101` regardless of how it is represented characterwise.

Answer (score 7):

The octal `char` notation ought to be of the form `\abc` where `a`, `b`, and `c`, are octal digits (i.e. in the inclusive range of `0` to `7`).

Your has four digits, so the compiler will interpret it as `\010` (*maximal munch*) followed by `1`.

That's a *multicharacter constant*, rather like `'12'`. Like `\abc`, that has an `int` type but the value is *implementation defined*, and the conversion to `c` in `printf` will have implementation-defined behaviour. Your helpful compiler is alerting you of that and, not surprisingly, is using correct terminology.

Did you mean to write `'\101'`? If you did, and what you really wanted was the upper case letter A, then write `'A'` for portable C.